# IronRuby - how to require .NET assemblies without strong name?

Tags: ironruby, require

[This page](http://www.ironruby.net/Documentation/.NET/Assemblies) on the IronRuby help website talks about being able to 'require' some well-known assemblies such as System.Windows.Forms without needing to crank out the entire '*ah-come-on-gimme-a-break-here-you-cannot-be-serious*' strong name of the assembly.

In the docs it says this:

```
>>> require "System.Windows.Forms"  
=> true
```

But when I try the same 'require', I get this:

```
>>> require "System.Windows.Forms"
IronRuby.Libraries:0:in 'require': no such file to load -- System.Windows.Forms (LoadError) 
        from :0:in 'Initialize##1'
```

What might I be doing wrong? Could it be a setup problem? I can't see this "libs directory on the load path" that gets mentioned in the documentation. Is the documentation wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it *was* a setup problem - there were two copies of ir.exe in the IronRuby download, and I was using the wrong one.

Answer (score 7):

The way that this works is because the IronRuby guys have written a bunch of wrapper scripts.

Look in `<your ironruby install path>\lib\ironruby` and you'll see `System.Windows.Forms.rb`, `System.Drawing.rb` etc.

What happens when you do `require 'System.Windows.Forms'` is that IronRuby finds that rb file and runs it. The code inside that file just does the full strong-named require for you.

If you want to load other dll's that they haven't written wrappers for, you have 3 options:

1. require the full path to the dll (eg `c:\program files\whatever\whatever\blah.dll`)
2. require the strong name (this only works if it's in the GAC or somewhere else IronRuby can find dll's in)
3. use `load_assembly` - This is the most convenient, but IIRC it loads the dll into the `LoadFrom` context, not the `Load` context.
   If you don't understand what that means, then basically it's fine in testing, but don't do it in production :-)

Comment: Thanks - it's interesting to see how the IronRuby folk implemented this.

Comment: I had a different problem, and using `load_assembly` fixed it. Where can I find more details on the differences between `require` and `load_assembly`?